# How to embed google maps in iframe with search option

Tags: javascript, html

How to embed google maps in Iframe.When I click on menu in google maps screen,it will go to "share or embed map",where I get a url with iframe,but this doesn't works.So please give me a answer where iframe completely sits with google maps screen menu and search option,where user can type in something to search.I mean to say this image(google maps with search option)should fit in iframe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhTjF.jpg)

Comment: have you actually tried something on your own?

Comment: How ? Hmm surely by coding I assume

Comment: I think you might have to type some code with your keyboard or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This might help... Google map embedded within iframe 
   http://jsfiddle.net/RLuYw/

```
<iframe width="600" height="300" src="http://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&q=Pariser Platz, 10117 Berlin+(Brandenburger Tor)&ie=UTF8&t=&z=17&iwloc=B&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><a href="http://www.siteway.de/maps-generator/" title="Google Maps für Ihre Homepage">(c) Homepage Google Maps Generator</a></iframe>
```

if you want Google Map with search option  please check the below link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox